# Remote repository is incompatible with fsmonitor

Tags: git, repository, permission-denied

I'm quite new in Stackoverflow.
I've some issue with git in local installation.
Few weeks ago we had resumed our server for a disk problem, so we've lost permissions in a lot of folders. Server is a Windows 2012 R2 and we work in a domain.

I'm using git to track versions especially for tex files, after server problem, if I try to make a new commit I have the following errors:

> warning: remote repository '//servername/folder/subfolder' is incompatible with fsmonitor

> fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied
> About first problem, I've no idea how to solve or which setting I've to check.

About second problem indeed, I've checked permission of all '.git' dir and all is ok with my user (I'm the owner of the files). This is really strange, because if I try to edit with a text editor, COMMIT_EDITMSG I can write. I also tried to open COMMIT_EDITMSG directly by gitbash with nano editor, I can write and save without problems.
Thanks in advance.

I checked about similar problem on internet before writing here. I tried to reset permission of files and I checked 'fsmonitor' option without success

Comment: May be this one: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-fsmonitor--daemon#_caveats "*By default, the fsmonitor daemon **refuses to work against network-mounted repositories**… Note, however, that the fsmonitor daemon is not guaranteed to work correctly with all network-mounted repositories and such use is considered experimental.*"

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for reply.
In the config file I tied to add the row: fsmonitor.allowremote = true, but when I try to make a commit, I receive the error message: fatal: bad config line 9 in file .git/config
If I comment this row, old error message are displayed again.

Comment: Try `git config fsmonitor.allowRemote true` instead of editing config with a text editor. The syntax in config file is different from just `fsmonitor.allowremote = true`.

Comment: But the real solution would be not to work with the repository on a network mount and not run `fsmonitor` in it but instead to have a local clone, commit locally and push.

Comment: Hi Phd.
Just tried, following your instructions. Using command you suggest me, in config file (I checked config file and a new [fsmonitor] section was added with a new row: alloRemote = true).
Errors now are:
error: daemon not online yet
fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied
About daemon, I don't know how to wake up it, about permission, as I written, I checked several times and I'm owner of .git dir and all files inside, so I've no idea.
Thanks anyway